# Copied XIB files cached

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xib

Few days ago I've started making applications for iPhone.
So far - it went quite well.
I decided to make application that's going to use both flip-like navigation and tab.
So, it's something like this:
TAB 1 (xib1) -> Static content
TAB 2 (xib2) -> Static content + BUTTON [CLICK: Flip to xib3.]
TAB 3 (xib4) -> Static content.
To create that flip effect I've used template in XCode (utility application) and copied over 4 files named: MainView.xib, MainViewController.m, MainViewController.h and FlipView.xib, FlipViewController.m and FlipViewController.h . 
**Problem is:** Those MainView.xib and FlipViewController.xib are somehow cached (probably those .h and .m files as well - but I didn't test that), so even if I make change on those - it won't affect application when I run simulator.
Any idea what should I do? I cleaned both build folder, I did clean function from menu bar, I also did reset simulator from Simulator bar (to restore original settings).
I'm using XCode 4 and Mac OS X 10.6 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the XIB files, and the other files you wish to use, are being built as part of the target in your new project.

In Xcode 4, you can do this using the File Inspector utility:

- Open the Project Navigator by pressing Cmd-1 or navigating in the menus View > Navigators > Project.
- Select the file you are interested in.
- Open the File Inspector utility by pressing Cmd-Opt-1 or selecting the menu item View > Utilities > File Inspector.
- Scroll down in the File Inspector utility till you find the "Target Membership" section.
- Make sure the checkbox is ticked next to the target that is building your application.

Comment: Nope, this didn't work. I checked out if these files are part of same target (my project) and they were. Thanks for trying tho.